# Change the Authentication Prompt to be inside a terminal?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am want to access my desktop PC with ubuntu via SSH from my laptop. So when the terminal required to use this prompt, is there a way I can change it to be inside the terminal instead of a 'visual' popup?

[image: Image of the prompt box]

Comment: What OS and version do you have on the laptop? Which app are you using for ssh on the laptop?

Comment: Confused: You are showing us an RDP window, which is a completely different method of access. An ssh connection (like from a terminal) does not prompt for color management. Perhaps your question is not yet clear enough about exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

Is not about the ssh, I want this kind of prompts to be inside the terminal so I can input while I'm inside a ssh connection which is via terminal.